# How can i drag the dot icon in dotline?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code is as below:

[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/9NpS4/)

Now I use click event to change selected dot style.

But my question is :

how can I implement dragging the dot icon in dotline?

Please kindly help me, I try this for a couple of hours.

### html

```
<title>Drag</title>
<body>
    <div class="b_step33">
        <div class="block_right">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="dot">
                    <div class="dotline" id="hc_pc">
                        <i class="dot1" onClick="$(this).parent().find('i').removeClass('selected');$(this).addClass('selected');"></i>
                        <i class="dot2" onClick="$(this).parent().find('i').removeClass('selected');$(this).addClass('selected');"></i>
                        <i class="dot3 selected" onClick="$(this).parent().find('i').removeClass('selected');$(this).addClass('selected');"></i>
                        <i class="dot4" onClick="$(this).parent().find('i').removeClass('selected');$(this).addClass('selected');"></i>
                        <i class="dot5" onClick="$(this).parent().find('i').removeClass('selected');$(this).addClass('selected');"></i>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I'd do it - http://jsfiddle.net/9NpS4/34/

I've tidied up the inline `onClick`, added a draggable element of the selected state which moves to the position of the selected item and this is done on page load and every time one of the dots are clicked.

**jQuery**

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ snap: '.snappable'});

$('i.snappable').click(function() {
   $('i.snappable').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    changePosition();
});



$(document).ready(function() {
    changePosition();
});

function changePosition() {

    var position = $("i.selected").position();
    var left = position.left;

    // $("i#draggable").css('left', left); 
    // animated version looks more polished to me but you can use this line if you want to

    $("i#draggable").animate({
        left: left,
     }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });   
}
```

**Please note that you'll need to include `jQueryUI` with the `draggable` library for this to work.**

**HTML**

```
<li class="dot">
    <div class="dotline" id="hc_pc">
        <i id="draggable"></i>
        <i class="dot1 snappable"></i>
        <i class="dot2 snappable"></i>
        <i class="dot3 snappable selected"></i>
        <i class="dot4 snappable"></i>
        <i class="dot5 snappable"></i>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
i#draggable { 
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/ybhGSUc.png) no-repeat;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**edit**

The draggable object was a bit of a mess - it could be dragged anywhere, try this instead:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ snap: '.snappable', snapMode: "inner", containment: "parent"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9NpS4/37/

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, you did a awesome job! :) works perfectly